# Quantiles function in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: histogram, aggregate-functions, google-bigquery

BigQuery with Legacy SQL has a pretty convenient [`QUANTILES`](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions) function to quickly get a histogram of values in a table without specifying the buckets by hand.

I can't find a nice equivalent in aggregation functions available in [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#aggregate-functions). Did I miss something obvious, or otherwise, what's the standard way of emulating it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for the [`APPROX_QUANTILES` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_quantiles) :) One of the examples from the docs is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(x, 2) AS approx_quantiles
FROM UNNEST([NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) AS x;

+------------------+
| approx_quantiles |
+------------------+
| [1, 5, 10]       |
+------------------+
```

Note that it returns an array, but if you want the elements of the array as individual rows, you can unnest the result:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  quant, offset
FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(x, 2) AS quants
  FROM UNNEST([NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) AS x
)) AS quant WITH OFFSET
ORDER BY offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

If approximate values don't work for you, you can use the [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#percentile_cont) function.